# Jenkins 2.204.2: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to write a script to automatize Jenkins agent nodes creation. I'm using Jenkins 2.204.2 provided by the jenkins/jenkins:lts-alpine docker image which, as far as I know, is supposed to be the "official" Jenkins image.

The following line:

```
ComputerLauncher launcher = new SSHLauncher("host", 22, "cr-id", (String)null, (String)null, (String)null, (String)null, (Integer)null, (Integer)null, (Integer)null)
```

raises the following exception:

```
2020-02-12 16:51:22.453+0000 [id=49]   WARNING j.util.groovy.GroovyHookScript#execute: Failed to run script file:/var/jenkins_home/init.groovy.d/create-nodes.groovy
 groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher(java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String, null, null, null, null, null, null, null)
```

However, I used code examples from here https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/218154667-Create-a-Permanent-Agent-from-Groovy-Console

Here is the plugin version:

[image]

Could anyone please let me know what might be the problem here ?

Many thanks in advance.

Kind regards,

Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question. It appears that for the version 1.31.1 of the SSH Build Agents plugin the coorect code is as follows:

```
ComputerLauncher launcher = new hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher("host", 22, ck1.id, (String)null, (String)null, (String)null, (String)null, (Integer)null, (Integer)null, (Integer)null, new NonVerifyingKeyVerificationStrategy())
```

Kind regards,

Nicolas